# GIT Api create release

Tags: github

I'm writing a powershell script that will generate a build package, create a new GitHub release and upload the package as an asset to the release.

The problem that I'm currently facing that when I post the release the API just returns an array of the existing releases. Via the UI I can create a release, so I don't think this is an rights issue.

Post request:

Url: http:// [github-instance]/api/v3/repos/[owner]/[repository]/releases

Body:

```
{
  "tag_name": "v0.1.1",
  "target_commitish": "master",
  "name": "v0.1.1",
  "body": "Description of the release",
  "draft": false,
  "prerelease": true
}
```

Respose Headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin →*
Access-Control-Expose-Headers →ETag, Link, Retry-After, X-GitHub-OTP, X-                
RateLimit-Limit, X-RateLimit-Remaining, X-RateLimit-Reset, X-OAuth-Scopes, X- 
Accepted-OAuth-Scopes, X-Poll-Interval
Cache-Control →private, max-age=60, s-maxage=60
Content-Length →2
Content-Security-Policy →default-src 'none'
Content-Type →application/json; charset=utf-8
Date →Thu, 28 Jun 2018 08:04:12 GMT
ETag →"683f9876e78713e234cb4f8a08c1223f"
Server →GitHub.com
Status →200 OK
Strict-Transport-Security →max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains
Vary →Accept, Authorization, Cookie, X-GitHub-OTP
X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes →
X-Content-Type-Options →nosniff
X-Frame-Options →deny
X-GitHub-Enterprise-Version →2.13.4
X-GitHub-Media-Type →github.v3; format=json
X-GitHub-Request-Id →f94c5fa8-cfd1-4fc8-b6d5-678785c17448
X-OAuth-Scopes →admin:pre_receive_hook, read:discussion, read:org, 
read:public_key, read:repo_hook, read:user, repo, user:email, user:follow
X-Runtime-rack →0.092114
X-XSS-Protection →1; mode=block
```

Any idea what could be the issue?

Comment: Double check if the request is really POST

Comment: Did this multiple times. Here is a [screenshot](https://imgur.com/tjLkhQx) of postman .